# Compare two arrays with their respective directories in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have primary files array and secondary files array in shell script. Both these arrays will contain file numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash
pri=(958 955 675 703 936 933 930 927 908 905 902 899 709)
snd=(953 947 943 939 916 915 1023 889 1010 1054 977 970 966)

# directories where we need to compare
primary=/primaries
secondary=/secondaries

echo "primary files: ${pri[@]}"
echo "secondary files: ${snd[@]}"

# now compare files in primary array `pri[@]` with `/primaries` directory. All files in primary array should be present in `/primaries` directory.
# and compare secondary array `snd[@]` with `/secondaries` directory. All files in secondary array should be present in `/secondaries` directory.
# If any of the file is missing, log a message.
```

Now all the files in primary array `pri[@]` should be present in `/primaries` directories and all the files in secondary array `snd[@]` should be present in `/secondaries` directories. File name is like this in both the directories `proc_1041_test.data`. Here 1041 is the file number.

How can I compare primary array file number with files in primaries directories and similarly for secondaries as well?

**Note:** `/primaries` and `/secondaries` directories can have sub directories in them so I just need to look for files in those two parent directories only not in any of the sub directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - How to find all files NOT in array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/354419)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one of the arrays:

```
for num in "${pri[@]}"; do
    name="proc_${num}_test.data"
    if [ ! -f "$primary/$name" ]; then
        printf '"%s" not found in "%s"\n' "$name" "$primary" >&2
    fi
done
```

That is, loop over the numbers in the array, construct the expected filename and test whether the expected filename exists¹ in the directory. If it doesn't, write a diagnostic message to the standard error stream.

Doing both sets of files in one go:

```
set -- "$primary" "$secondary"

typeset -n array
for array in pri snd; do
    for num in "${array[@]}"; do
        name="proc_${num}_test.data"
        if [ ! -f "$1/$name" ]; then
            printf '"%s" not found in "%s"\n' "$name" "$1" >&2
        fi
    done
    shift
done
```

This introduces a name reference variable `array`.  When accessing `${array[@]}`, the variable whose name has been assigned to `array` (in the loop, first `pri` then `snd`) will be access instead.

The directory names `$primary` and `$secondary` are assigned to the positional parameters `$1` and `$2` before the loop using `set`, and within the loop we `shift` `$2` into `$1` when we are done with the original `$1`.

---

<sup>¹ and is a *regular* file (or symlink to accessible regular file), change to `[ ! -e "$primary/$name" ] && [ ! -L "$primary/$name" ]` to check that the file exists regardless of its type.</sup>

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The test for `-L` will be true if a link of the name used exists. But that does **not** mean that the **file** that that link points to (the actual file that contains data) actually exists. Yes, there is `something` at the position, but not necessarily an actual file with content.

Comment: @isaac, yes, but here `[ -L "$primary/$name" ]` returning true means the `$primary/$name` file of type symlink exists. That second `[` is actually only run in the case where the first `[` succeeds, that is where we can't tell whether the file the link is (eventually) resolving to exists.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I know. But when the second test returns true, the whole test returns true, and that may be understood that the final file that the link points to is in place and is readable. The first test will fail if the final file is not present. That is what should be the intent of the whole test. Maybe (and only maybe), if the `-f` test fails, then raise a warning that there is a link of the same name and that it is broken because the final file does not exist. That is a completely different logic and test.

Comment: @isaac, the OP didn't specify what type of files those were or may be, whether they were regular files, fifos, directories, devices... or symlinks. It's not uncommon to create _flag_ files as symlinks whose target may not resolve to an actual path for instance. `-f` is for _regular_ file only after symlink resolution, the ¹ note is for all other types of files. For _readable_, you'd need `-r` (which does not imply `-f`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are missing the point.

Comment: @isaac The `-L` test needs to be there if the user is interested in symbolic links. If the `-e` test fails, there could still be a (dead) symbolic link there. Not until the `-L` test fails can we say that there is truly nothing there.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, something exists. But that something is incomplete. There is no file to read data from, the link may be broken. The `-f` test will be true if there is a file that contains data (even if the file is actually behind a link).

Comment: @isaac Stéphane's point is that a symbolic link (no matter if it points to something valid or not) is still a _file_. This is why his last words in his edit to my answer says "regardless of its type". He's including symbolic links as a valid file type, which it is.

Comment: @Kusalananda A link could not store data. I do understand Stéphane's point, thanks for the reiteration. He is testing that `something` exists. That is not my point. My point is that a simple `-f` test is testing something else, namely, that a file exist with data, even after following a link. Including a `-L` test is against such idea.

Comment: @isaac The destination of a symbolic link is data...

Comment: @Kusalananda Being sarcastic helps no one.

Comment: @isaac I was not sarcastic. A symbolic link is a file that contains data. The data is a path. This is not sarcasm.

Comment: @Kusalananda I expected that you knew that a link can not accept a `echo "some data: Hello World!" >linkname` only the actual file that resides after following the link.

Comment: @isaac If the symbolic link exists, should it be reported as not existing just because the target of the link does not exist? If one is interested in finding out whether a name _exists_ in a directory, should one weed out symbolic links just because they point into the void? That doesn't make the name not exist.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, that is not nothing I am saying. What I am saying is that if you are testing if there is a file where to store data, a `-f` is both necessary and sufficient. Additionally, if the `-f` test fails, you may either remove the link (as it is broken) or raise an error that a link of the same name exists, or recreate the destination file or ... else ... . That is different than assuming that a true return of both test combined (as presented) mean that some data could be sent to the file (remember: `echo "data" >filename`). That is a serious limitation.